# Verify Receipt Apple Not Using the Password

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am attempting to validate a receipt in the sandbox environment (https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt).  The response looks successful and it is showing me the LatestReceiptInfo and any InApp transactions.

The part that is confusing me is that I am able to do it with an invalid secret as well.  I am even able to verify with a receipt that was generated from a very different app.  It appears as if validation is ignoring the shared secret entirely.

I would expect a status code of 21003 for the valid receipt that wasn't created by my app.  I would also expect a 21004 for the invalid secret.   In both cases I get a status code of 0 and the receipt is available.

There is something that I am not understanding about how verification works.  Is this expected behavior for the sandbox?

Below is the response body that i am sending to verify.

```
{
  "receipt-data": "MyReceiptData",
  "password": "FakePassword",
  "exclude-old-transactions": true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your purchase item `isn't an subscription`. then apple will ignore the `password`.

Only verify the `password` when it's an `subscription`.

Answer (score 1):

Password is required now, don't know why Apple doesn't put these documents together:
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/configure-in-app-purchase-settings/generate-a-shared-secret-to-verify-receipts/

Only 3 steps:

1. Log in to appstore connect, from Users and Access, click Shared Secret.
2. Click Generate.
3. Copy the code and use it for your transactions receipt for all of your apps with auto-renewable subscriptions.